# How to install dev version of Twitter OAuth by Abraham via Composer?

Tags: php, twitter, github, oauth, composer-php

I am trying to install DEV version of this repo https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth/tree/dev since it supports PSR-4, but when i add to my `composer.json` something like this

```
"abraham/twitteroauth": "dev-master"
or
"abraham/twitteroauth": "dev-master@dev"
```

I always get `master` - https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth/tree/master

How to get `dev`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When requiring a branch with composer, you need to prefix it with `dev-` like you did with master in your example (`dev-master`). So, in order to require the `dev` branch, you need to require it like:

```
"abraham/twitteroauth": "dev-dev"
```

**Edit**

The actual repository being required by composer is [8yabusa/twitteroauth](https://github.com/8yabusa/twitteroauth) which is a fork of [kensnyder/twitteroauth](https://github.com/kensnyder/twitteroauth), which is a fork of the original [abraham/twitteroauth](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth/tree/master). The `dev` branch is not present on `8yabusa/twitteroauth`, which means composer does not know about it.

The problem is that the original repository does not have a `composer.json` file, meaning composer does not know how to install it. You could manually add the original repository as a package in your `composer.json as outlined in the [composer docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#repositories).

```
{
    "require": {
        "abraham/twitteroauth": "dev-dev"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "abraham/twitteroauth",
                "description": "Twitter oauth",
                "version": "dev-dev",
                "keywords": ["Twitter API", "Twitter oAuth"],
                "license": "MIT",
                "authors": [
                  {
                    "name": "Abraham Williams",
                    "email": "abraham@abrah.am"
                  }
                ],
                "require": {
                  "php": ">=5.3.2"
                },
                "autoload": {
                  "files": ["twitteroauth/OAuth.php"]
                },
                "source": {
                    "type": "git",
                    "url": "https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth",
                    "reference": "origin/dev"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: It does not work :( -   Problem 1 - The requested package abraham/twitteroauth dev-dev could not be found.

Comment: @SmxCde I edited my answer to load the original repo instead of the fork.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, looks like it works! There is only thing was unclear for me, is that i still have to add "abraham/twitteroauth": "dev-dev" to my "require" section. I think it would be great if you could edit your example and provide full composer.json content example to avoid confusions.